# Set Height to Custom ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, view, android-custom-view, onmeasure

I have a custom `Linearlayout` that combines some views together. I want this `Linearlayout` to be `wrap_content` for the height. I tried adding layout params in the custrucor like this

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                       ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
setLayoutParams(params);
```

but it has no effect. the height is still `match_parent`. I also tried to calculate height in `onMeasure` based on the height of children like this

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    measureChildren(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
    int size = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <getChildCount();i++) {
        size += getChildAt(i).getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    int height = resolveSize(size,heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec,height);
}
```

It also does not have any effect. So where is the problem?

Comment: Are you using weights for any of the children? What orientation are you using for this LinearLayout subclass?

Comment: i'm using vertical orientation and no weigt. caculate children height is correct but doesn't apply

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `LinearLayout` subclass arranges views vertically, this code which overrides the `onMeasure` method should work:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    final int containerWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    final int containerHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    final int childWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(containerWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    final int childHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(containerHeight, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

    View child;
    int totalChildHeight = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        child = getChildAt(i);

        if (child == null || child.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            continue;

        measureChildWithMargins(child, childWidthMeasureSpec, 0, childHeightMeasureSpec, totalChildHeight);           

        totalChildHeight += child.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(containerWidth, totalChildHeight);
}
```

Keep in mind that this essentially overrides `LinearLayout's` measurement logic. While this code pretty much does the same thing, except in a more explicit manner, it also completely ignores `weights` given to children, and so if you require `weights`, you may need to apply more logic here.

In addition, I should note that this measurement logic assumes no padding exists. If you have padding, you should initialise `totalChildHeight` to `bottomPadding` + `topPadding`.

Answer (score -1):

Hi In **onMeasure** method you have to add this after calculating the totalheight required you have to use makeMeasureSpec as mention below:

heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(heightRequired, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

Its works for me...